# form submit trigger in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML, a form can be submitted by

- clicking the submit button
- pressing enter when the focus is on the submit button
- by pressing enter on the input field

Is there a way to find out which of the three methods was used to submit the form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery detect which button submitted form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628750/jquery-detect-which-button-submitted-form)

Comment: I believe the difference is that Lujaw wants to know if the submit came from a click on the button, an enter-key event when focus was on the submit button, or an enter-key event when focus was on the input field. @Lujaw: is this correct?

Comment: @Peter Yes, you are absolutely correct.
I need to apply different function in these three conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML doesn't have any built-in way of knowing, as far as I know. You'd have to catch the necessary events and keep the state in memory. Something like the following:

- Set a `bool` to true when the input receives focus. Set it back to false when it loses focus.
- Set a `bool` to true when the button receives focus. Set it back to false when it loses focus.
- Subscribe to the click event on the button, set a `bool` to true
- Subscribe to the keydown event of the keyboard, check whether it is the enter-key and set a `bool` to true.

Now you should have the necessary information to know what actions the user took to submit the form. jQuery should be able to help you with all these events.

Also, I believe the form is also submitted when the form has focus (so not just the button or the input) and you press enter. I'm not sure if this is the actual form having focus, or any control inside the form.

So, what you're trying to achieve will require some hacking around. Are you sure you can't provide your users the experience you want in some other way?

Comment: thanks @Peter, used boolean/flag values to differentiate the conditions. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) method of jquery to capture if a user is pressing the enter key. Along with the [`mousedown`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) method to capture the click. The jquery and HTML code would look like this:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    Name<input type="text" />
    Address<input type="text" />
    <button id="submitBtn" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('#submitBtn').keypress(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('You pressed "enter" key on the submit button');  
    }
    event.stopPropagation();

});

$('#myForm').keypress(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('You pressed "enter" key in the input field');    
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#submitBtn').mousedown(function(event){
   alert('You clicked submit'); 
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4xbN/)

Answer (score -1):

Just apply different function to each action. To prevent the form fires its default action, you have to put `return false;` or `event.preventDeafult();` in the callback function.

see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6krYM/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='input'>
    <input type='submit' value='submit' id='submit-button'>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){
    alert("click on submit button");
    return false;
});

$("#input").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("press enter in text");
    }
});

$("#submit-button").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        alert("press enter on button");
    }
    return false;
});
```